# How to create Toast from AutoCompleteTextView selected item?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-toast

I am a newbie android learner. I am trying to create toast when the item from the AutoCompleteTextView is selected by the user. I am reading the value from strings.xml ,which is working fine but i am confused how do I (what even handler) i needed to create toast. 
below is my code 
    1- activity.xml

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
/>

strings.xml
<string-array name="termsarray">
<item>emulator</item>
<item>ant</item>
<item>string.xml</item>
    <item>activity</item>
    <item>workspace</item>
    <item>adt</item>
    <item>manifest.xml</item>
    <item>package</item>
    <item>layout</item>
    <item>toast</item>
    <item>adb</item>
</string-array> 
//activity.java
public class TermActivity extends Activity {

 String[] categories;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    categories=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.termsarray);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_term);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, categories);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = 
            (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);
    textView.setThreshold(3);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handle that on a listener.**Try this:**

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "Position clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i m getting following error on context "context cannot be resolved to a variable" I changed to getBaseContext() but it only give me first index position every time.

Comment: You can either create a global variable that holds the Context and assign it at the start of the onCreate method or you can just use the word "this" instead (as long as it's in the onCreate method).

For the position, try swapping it for id.

Comment: complete version is posted below

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
         String str = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
             if(textView.getText().toString().equals("string.xml"))
              {
                  Toast.makeText(TermActivity.this, "A string resource provides text strings for your application with optional text styling and formatting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               //other logic
              }
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
         String str = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
      }
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: thanks for feedback sir, i will keep it in my mind for next time.